# Equivalent of CellMouseEnter in DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, mousemove

Is there some sort of equivalent of CellMouseEnter from the winforms DataGridView control for use in WPF? I cant seem to find anything in the documention.

Or is there a more efficient way of doing it instead of the MouseMove event on the whole data grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subscribe to the enter event on the individual cells like this:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="SomeHandler" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using this how can I then find the index of the cell in the datagrid? Or I have to compare the position relative to the DataGrid control or something?

Comment: @gummy24: I do not know and it should not matter, as you should avoid operations based indices and position in the first place. It probably is not easy to do in WPF for a reason.

Comment: Actually scrap what i just said. The sender is a datagridcell, so I can just use its properties to reconstruct its position. Many thanks!